# Gradle android optimize packagingOptions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have that project structure:

```
-gradle root
           |-clients
                    |-client 1
                    |-client 2
                        ... 
                    |-client N
           |-libs
                    |-android lib 1
                    |-android lib 2
                        ...
                    |-android lib N
                    |-java lib 1
                    |-java lib 2
                        ...     
                    |-java lib N
```

In each client build file I have the `packagingOptions` to exclude options.
Something like that:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

How could I optimize that block and move it for example in my root gradle build file?
I don't really want to copy paste it across all clients.

Comment: For Kotlin DSL see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811835/8583692)

Answer (score 21):

Found solution.
Credits: https://github.com/frankdu/android-gradle-dagger-tutorial

I've created separate build file and moved that settings there.
File *android_common.gradle*

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

Then in each client put that line:

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/android_common.gradle"
```

And finally excluded `packagingOptions` from my clients build files.
In additional I've moved another common configurations there.
Looks clean, simple and nice after that.

Comment: rootDir is not available in android 1.0

Comment: Thanks, that just example I'm not using ${rootDir} in my build config.

Comment: can provide option if image(png) inside drawable folder?

Answer (score 6):

For the record, most of your package options are already the default.

See [PackagingOptions Gradle documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.0/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html)

```
Pick first: none
Merge: /META-INF/services/**
Exclude:
/META-INF/LICENSE
/META-INF/LICENSE.txt
/META-INF/NOTICE
/META-INF/NOTICE.txt
/LICENSE
/LICENSE.txt
/NOTICE
/NOTICE.txt
/META-INF/*.DSA (all DSA signature files)
/META-INF/*.EC (all EC signature files)
/META-INF/*.SF (all signature files)
/META-INF/*.RSA (all RSA signature files)
/META-INF/maven/** (all files in the maven meta inf directory)
/META-INF/proguard/* (all files in the proguard meta inf directory)
**/.svn/** (all .svn directory contents)
**/CVS/** (all CVS directory contents)
**/SCCS/** (all SCCS directory contents)
**/.* (all UNIX hidden files)
**/.*/** (all contents of UNIX hidden directories)
**/*~ (temporary files)
**/thumbs.db
**/picasa.ini
**/protobuf.meta
**/about.html
**/package.html
**/overview.html
**/_*
**/_*/**
```

Comment: [PackagingOptions Gradle documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html) link is dead. Can you update it?

Comment: @anticafe, check this link https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.0/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Answer (score 2):

For those who cant find fresh documentation link for [PackagingOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.0/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html).

*This must be comment to LanDenLabs answer but I cant post a comment without 50 rep :(*