# Build gradle : Could not find method packagingOptions() for arguments root Project "fasterDev"

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies, build.gradle

I am using single build.gradle file in application.
Regarding version 1.6 it's working properly.
but I want to use this for location update with module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:fp9.0.0'
}
```

Here is my build.gradle.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

Any tutorial or suggestion for this?

Logs:

```
org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method packagingOptions() for arguments [build_b54s9k8r9uto6awxmkxnu2ipo$_run_closure3@3a2d3196] on root project 'fasterDev'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You've provided the `packagingOptions` outside of the `android` closure, that is the reason Gradle supposes, that it's some root project's method.

Just move it into the `android` closure, as:

```
android {
    ...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thank for your time & suggestion .but if I placed this inside the android as you  suggest. I will get" Duplicate files copied in APK " 
& log :: You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
 android {
   packagingOptions {
     exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver'
   }
 }

Can you suggest more on this.

Comment: That means, that the exception you've got first is solved and build script is correct now. You just need to improve the provided configuration. Have you tried to exclude the `lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver`? If this is `.so` native lib, then try to change `exclude` to `pickFirst`, this will include the only first one occurance of the lib.

Comment: great .Thanks a ton. exclude to pickFirst it's new to me. If you have any article on this. please share a link.

Comment: Still I was not able to solve this. but I am trying the same things.

Answer (score 3):

With newer versions of [AGP](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) (Android Gradle Plugin), the exclude function is deprecated and replaced with `resources.excludes` property.

[Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (*build.gradle.kts*):

```kotlin
android {
  // ...
  packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE*"
    resources.excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    // OR
    // resources.excludes += setOf(
    //   "META-INF/LICENSE*",
    //   "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    // )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped me, however there is an answer in the most up-to-date SDK the syntax became slightly different https://stackoverflow.com/a/75718985/3649629