# Could not find method packagingOption()

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> This project is eclipse project when i try to convert into android
>   studio and add the packagingOption in gradle file it will show me
>   bellow error in android studio 2.2 how can i fix it

```
Error:(23, 0) Could not find method packagingOption() for arguments [build_cgom5qnlyrf01zs8t9c0ozn8x$_run_closure1$_closure6@1333a698] on project ':kOOPSCv2' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 3
        versionName '1.2'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {}
    packagingOption{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':kOOPSCv2FileChooser')
    compile files('libs/aquery.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37409760/1769274

Comment: thanks for your help and now i also got the actual reason of error i need to change packagingOption to packagingOptions.

Comment: can i post this as the answer ?

Comment: sorry you are late i paste it if u want then paste it

Answer (score 0):

Replace the word **packagingOption** to **packagingOptions**