# How to replace deprecated packagingOptions in Android Gradle build files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have migrated to gradle 8 my android build gradle files show

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0-alpha01' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0-alpha01' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44.2' apply false
}

tasks.register('clean') {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now in my module gradle.build files packagingOptions is highlighted as deprecated

```
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
    }
}
```

[image]

I thought I had found this solution

```
packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes.add('/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}')
}
```

which does not work!!!
what is the correct replacement for the deprecated packagingOptions exclude?

The version of android studio I am using is

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 1
Build #AI-223.4884.69.2231.9486165, built on January 13, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.5+0-17.0.5b653.23-9410051 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

This appears to fix it

```
packagingOptions.resources.excludes.add('/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}')
```

Comment: `'getResources()' is declared in unstable 'com.android.build.api.dsl.PackagingOptions' marked with @Incubating `

Answer (score 19):

This Method is Deprecated, this is doc

```kotlin
    @Deprecated("Renamed to packaging", replaceWith = ReplaceWith("packaging"))
    fun packagingOptions(action: Packaging.() -> Unit)


    val packaging: Packaging

    fun packaging(action: Packaging.() -> Unit)
```

**old:**

```kotlin
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
    }
}
```

**replace:**

```kotlin
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Weirdly, `packaging.resources.excludes` [shows to be deprecated](https://i.imgur.com/hCTARpd.png) to me, and `packagingOptions.resources.excludes` [looks OK](https://i.imgur.com/cEUmmPr.png) again. Are they changing it back? `8.1.0-alpha08`

Comment: With AGP `8.0.2`, the `packagingOptions.resources.excludes` causes build error with `Adding a packagingOptions block may help...` suggestion. And with AGP `8.1.0-rc01` the `packaging.resources.excludes` is deprecated, while the `packagingOptions.resources.excludes` is not deprecated and the build works. What's the correct and non-deprecated option for AGP `8.1.0` now?

Answer (score 10):

In Kotlin `AGP 8.0` I just prefixed `exludes` with **`it`** and the *deprecation warning* is now gone.

```
packaging {
        resources {
            it.excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"

        }
    }
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say `packaginOptions` is deprecated:

https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions

https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions

It says `excludes` is deprecated:

[image]

It's interesting that the 7.0 docs include `excludes` (https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions#excludes:kotlin.collections.MutableSet).

7.2 only has `exclude` (https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions#exclude(kotlin.String)) but explains what to swap it with:

> This function is deprecated. This method is deprecated. Use
> resources.excludes.add() or jniLibs.excludes.add() instead. Use
> jniLibs.excludes.add() for .so file patterns, and use
> resources.excludes.add() for all other file patterns.

Which is what you've done.

If you read the 8.0 docs and click through to `resources.excludes` https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions#excludes()

It gives an example:

> The set of excluded patterns. Java resources matching any of these
> patterns do not get packaged in the APK.
>
> Example: android.packagingOptions.resources.excludes += "**/*.exclude"

So you could try that. (which is looks like you have).

Are you sure its highlighted as deprecated, and not highlighted as `incubating` as written here in the 8.0 docs? https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions

Comment: its weird that its packagingOptions is "striked through" when its excludes that is actually deprecated

Comment: added an image from my project

Comment: are you using it inside of `android { }` or somewhere else?

Comment: inside android {}

Comment: @Blundell What if it is labelled as Incubating?

Comment: You can use it if it is incubating but it may disappear in future versions without deprecation first. So be aware when you bump the version.

Answer (score 0):

After Gradle 8 in Kotlin DSL you can do this:

```
packaging {
        resources {
            excludes.add("/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}")
            ...
        }
}
```